# Evaluating many expressions at once in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

In Intellij Idea, I'm looking for a way to evaluate many expressions in debug mode with one command.

Normally I can evaluate single command with `Right Click → Evaluate Expression` (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>). I would like to have possibility to evaluate a bunch of expressions like:

```
System.out.println(myVar1);
System.out.println(myVar2);
```

In Eclipse this is possible to execute such "script of expressions", but I can not find a solution in Idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to click "Code fragment mode" in the evaluate expression dialog (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>) and you can enter as many lines as you want instead of single line - which is default - "Expression mode".

[image]

[image]

Then you can switch back anytime using "Expression mode" button.

Answer (score 5):

You can either click the small fullscreen arrows button to the right of the Expression box, or press `shift`+`enter`.

> If you want to edit a multi-line expression or a code fragment, click  Expand in the Expression field or press ⇧⏎ to switch to the multi-line Code fragment view and back.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate such expressions in Evaluate window

```
System.out.println(myVar1);
System.out.println(myVar2);
```

The only thing here is that your whole result (not last) will appear not in the same window but in a console.

Answer (score 0):

well i was also struggling a lot with this, until i figured out that in the code it needs fully qualified paths for classes (for classes outside of java.*)

for example in this code below , i needed to find out , xml string representation from the document object (doc is my document object)

so i had to put this code into evaluate tab , which you can open from run window -after putting in below expression and clicking on evaluate - my xml string was printed in console

```
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory tf = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    java.io.StringWriter writer = new java.io.StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource(doc), new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer));
    System.out.println(writer.getBuffer().toString());
```

Comment: You don't need to do that. Just type ALT+Enter to import classes na info your evaluation context