# IntelliJ IDEA run highlighted code only

Tags: intellij-idea

How to run a highlighted code only in IntelliJ IDEA? Sometimes you don't need to run the whole file and wants to just run the some numbers of code. Are there any such choices in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating many expressions at once in Intellij Idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340908/evaluating-many-expressions-at-once-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to [evaluate arbitrary expressions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/evaluating-expressions.html#d1921831e204) (`Run` | `Evaluate Expression`):

> To evaluate a code fragment, click the **Code Fragment Mode** button and fill in the **Code Fragment** text box.

You can also use the [Scratches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/scratches.html) feature.

Since version 15 [Java scratches are runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33563160/104891).