# How to execute several lines of code with a variable in intellij idea Java debug?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, evaluation

I'd like to get a new value in intellij debug evaluate expression window and use it twice. Example:

```
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
resultSet.next();
resultSet.getObject(1);
```

Eventually, I'd like to see the value of `resultSet.getObject(1)` in the debug view.

Trying to do the above (with semi-columns) in the Evaluation window shows a red line and writes `invalid expression` when trying to evaluate the expression.

How to execute several lines of code with a variable in intellij idea Java debug?

Comment: Did you evaluate expression of a statement or code block ("Code Fragment Mode")?

Comment: @Idos Got it, Thanks. There's an option for a code block when clicking on `Code Fragment Mode`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340908/evaluating-many-expressions-at-once-in-intellij-idea